# Existe algum modo de gerar um select com not exists sem que a coluna de ID retorne violação de PK

Tags: sql

É possível criar um insert com algo semelhante a esse select

| CodEmbalagem | Codproduto |
| --- | --- |
| 11263830 | 19867 |
| 11263831 | 55106 |
| 11263832 | 125390 |
| 11263833 | 740 |
| 11263834 | 1 |

`(5 rows affected)`

| CodEmbalagem | Codproduto |
| --- | --- |
| 11263831 | 275104 |
| 11263832 | 591695 |
| 11263833 | 690041 |
| 11263834 | 99383 |
| 11263835 | 806171 |

```
insert into WMS_F19.dbo.Embalagem 
SELECT * FROM WMS_F02.dbo.Embalagem E19 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM WMS_F19.dbo.Embalagem E26 WHERE E19.CodProduto = E26.CodProduto)
```

Porém retorna violação na coluna `CodEmbalagem` pois já existe os valores daquela coluna na outra tabela.

A necessidade é inserir os produtos sem violar a PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma coisa que percebi é que `E19.CodProduto = E26.CodProduto` só será verdade quando já existir na `E19`, que é o caso onde não deve inserir (novamente). Essa comparação é com o `CodProduto`, e o erro é de duplicidade da `CodEmbalagem` - que deve ser a chave primária.

```
INSERT INTO WMS_F19.dbo.Embalagem (CodEmbalagem, Codproduto)
SELECT F02.CodEmbalagem, F02.Codproduto
FROM WMS_F02.dbo.Embalagem F02
WHERE F02.CodEmbalagem NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT F19.CodEmbalagem FROM WMS_F19.dbo.Embalagem F19)
```

Dessa forma você garante que serão inseridos apenas os `CodEmbalagem` que estão na tabela origem e não estão na tabela destino.

DETALHE: a validação está **apenas no `CodEmbalagem`**; caso sua chave seja composta e precise validar também o `CodProduto`, é preciso ajustar a condição na consulta.

Comment: deu certo, ficou show e entendi mais sobre o conceito, muitíssimo obrigado.

Comment: massa, man!! (depois aceita a resposta ;])